# Gson + List<> как сериализовать иерархию

Tags: java, json, ооп, gson

У меня есть следующая иерархия:

Продукт:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(1L);

    @Expose
    private long id;

    @Expose
    private String name;

    @Expose
    private long priceInCents;

    @Expose
    private int rate;

    public Product(String name, long priceInCents, int rate) {

        this.id = counter.getAndIncrement();

        this.name = name;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public Product(long id, String name, long priceInCents, int rate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public Product(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return id == product.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Категория с продуктами:

```
import coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva.model.products.Product;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@Data
public abstract class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(1L);

    @Expose
    protected long id;

    @Expose
    protected String title;

    @Expose
    protected List<Product> products;

    public Category(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category() {
        this.id = counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", products=" + products +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return id == category.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

И каталог со всеми категориями:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Catalog implements Serializable {

    private List<Category> categories;

}
```

Я знаю, что можно получить адаптер для списка ---> `Type itemsListType = new TypeToken<List<GoodsItem>>() {}.getType();`, но у меня не совсем та ситуация( Помогите, пожалуйста, как это можно отправить?

Так же я пыталась просто сериализовать, методом `gson.toJson(catalog)` но на фронт приходило это `{}`

Comment: gson.toJson(catalog) - правильное решение. Если JSON в итоге пустой получается, то что-то не то с настройками сериализации. Покажите как вы gson инициализируете. Также, возможно, вам не нужны `@Expose` аннотации - возможно вы так gson настроили, что поля с ними игнорируются? Так же можно поробовать убрать все ваши аннотации вообще - возможно там конфликт какой-то.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ я инициализировала так: 
```GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setPrettyPrinting();
builder.excludeFeldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
gson = bulder.create();```

Comment: Вот и ответ. У вас в классе Catalog нет Expose аннотации. Потому и Json пустой, т.к. вы явно запретили сериализации полей без этой аннотации. Надо или этот запрет убрать или аннотацию добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в классе Catalog нет Expose аннотации. Потому и Json пустой, т.к. вы явно запретили сериализации полей без этой аннотации. Надо или этот запрет убрать или аннотацию добавить

Comment: ой дура... Спасибо)

Comment: Заработало )) извиняюсь за невнимательность

Comment: Не за что извиняться - в том и суть работы программиста - не сдаваться при проблемах, находить обходные решения и накапливать опыт, позволяющий предполагать как код должен работать и что в нём может сломаться) Сегодня вы выросли как специалист, т.к. этот случай в памяти отложится и будет помогать в дальнейшем)

Answer (score 0):

Это оказалось проще, чем я могла подумать - пришлось только полазить немного в документации. Надеюсь, кому-то поможет!)

```
import coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva.model.catalog.Catalog;
import coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva.model.categories.Category;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
public class CatalogTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Catalog> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Catalog catalog) throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("categories");
        jsonWriter.beginArray();

        for (Category category : catalog.getCategories()) {
            jsonWriter.beginObject();
            jsonWriter.name("id");
            jsonWriter.value(category.getId());
            jsonWriter.name("title");
            jsonWriter.value(category.getTitle());
            jsonWriter.name("products");

            jsonWriter.beginArray();
            category.getProducts().forEach(product -> {
                try {
                    jsonWriter.beginObject();

                    jsonWriter.name("id");
                    jsonWriter.value(product.getId());
                    jsonWriter.name("name");
                    jsonWriter.value(product.getName());
                    jsonWriter.name("price in cents");
                    jsonWriter.value(product.getPriceInCents());
                    jsonWriter.name("rate");
                    jsonWriter.value(product.getRate());

                    jsonWriter.endObject();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("IN write - {}", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            jsonWriter.endArray();

            jsonWriter.endObject();
        }

        jsonWriter.endArray();
        jsonWriter.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Catalog read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        //do nothing
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Clothes category",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Sweater",
          "price in cents": 65458,
          "rate": 45
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Jacket",
          "price in cents": 11111,
          "rate": 89
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Coat",
          "price in cents": 9999,
          "rate": 36
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Vest",
          "price in cents": 1200,
          "rate": 68
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Shorts",
          "price in cents": 45000,
          "rate": 90
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Casual dress",
          "price in cents": 36500,
          "rate": 79
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Food category",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Meet",
          "price in cents": 2132,
          "rate": 100
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Cookies",
          "price in cents": 1111,
          "rate": 90
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Bread",
          "price in cents": 777,
          "rate": 85
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "Apples",
          "price in cents": 454,
          "rate": 32
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Ice cream",
          "price in cents": 873,
          "rate": 79
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Toys category",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "Barbie",
          "price in cents": 12345,
          "rate": 80
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Cycle",
          "price in cents": 65432,
          "rate": 90
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Lorry",
          "price in cents": 10000,
          "rate": 55
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "name": "Little hare",
          "price in cents": 6400,
          "rate": 97
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "name": "Bricks",
          "price in cents": 1500,
          "rate": 100
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "Rocking horse",
          "price in cents": 10999,
          "rate": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Кажется, вы вручную сделали то, что библиотека и так должна для вас делать. Собственно библиотека как раз для того и нужна, чтобы вы сами этот код не писали. Посмотрите мой коммент под вопросом - возможно он поможет.